# Google Script TypeError Cannot Read Property

Tags: javascript, typeerror, google-sheets-api

I am writing a project for my own leisure based on baseball lineups. I am trying to place position numbers based on a random player (row). I check for the proper position (2 = catcher, 3 = first base,... etc.) and then place the number in the following free cell. However, I keep receiving this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property "1" from undefined. (line 38, file "PBR")

I think I need to reset the values somehow and have tried looking at other threads but I can't quite figure it out. It works only about 50% of the time probably because of how the randomization pans out.

```
function placePos(posNum){
  var j;
  rng = newSheet.getDataRange();
  array = rng.getValues();
  j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (array.length + 1));

  pos1 = array[j][1];
  pos2 = array[j][2];

  switch(posNum){
    case 2:
  if(((pos1 == 'C') || (pos2 == 'C')) && (newSheet.getRange(j+1, 4).isBlank())){
    newSheet.getRange(j+1, 4).setValue(posNum);
    delete pos1;
    delete pos2;
  }
  else{
    delete pos1;
    delete pos2;
    placePos(2);
  }
  break;

    case 3:
  if(((pos1 == '1B') || (pos2 == '1B')) && (newSheet.getRange(j+1, 4).isBlank())){
    newSheet.getRange(j+1, 4).setValue(posNum);
    delete pos1;
    delete pos2;
  }
  else{
    delete pos1;
    delete pos2;
    placePos(3);
  }
  break;


}
}
```

I call the placePos function twice but will call it more to fill out the entire column 1-9. I have tried looking a multiple other threads for help but have not been able to find a solution that helps.

Comment: `Math.random()` generates a number in the range [0, 1). If your array has a length of 10, this means that your valid indices are 0-9. Your equation will give you the floor of `[0, 1) * (11)`, which has a maximum of 10. However, your max index is 9. Solution is don't add 1 to your array.length.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the help, I wasn't looking at the random function at all